# Почему он жалуется на табуляцию?

Tags: python, discord.py

[image: Ошибка с консоли]

Где в коде ошибка с "табуляцией"

**Код** (pastebin) - https://pastebin.com/gdzxCb7y

```
    @client.command(aliases=['d'])
async def marry(ctx, member: discord.Member = None, amount = None): 
    

    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}... ")


    def check(m):
        return m.author == member

    try:
        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=10)
        


        if msg.content.lower() in ['y', 'yes','+','да',' принимаю ']:
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, твою дуэль принимает {member.mention} , Ждём результат боя")
            asyncio.sleep(3)
            test = random.randint(1, 2)
            if test == 1:  
                await ctx.send(f"Автор дуэли победитель (test text)")
            if test == 2: 
                await ctx.send(f"Автор дуэли проиграл test text")

        elif  msg.content.lower() in ['n', 'no', 'нет', 'отклоняю', '-']:
            await ctx.send(f"Дуэль не состояться - {ctx.author.mention}")
        else:
            await ctx.send("I did not understand that, aborting!")
    except asyncio.TimeoutError as e:
        print(e)
        await ctx.send("Время ожидание закончилось")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В строке на которую у Вас ругается программа получается смешивание пробелов и табов. Должны быть или только табы или только пробелы, что собственно и вызывает ошибку:
[image: Пример ошибки]
На данном скрине точки отмечают пробелы а сплошная линия табы.

P.S. Во многих IDE есть возможность конвертировать табы в пробелы и наоборот. Или подставлять сразу необходимое.

Comment: Боже спасибо вам огромное , не когда не думал что я на такое попаду , и как так вышло тоже не понимаю , большая благодарность вам

Comment: @TanderOFF Вышло легко ставить отступы удобнее табами а не пробелами. Главное настройки IDE чтобы это скрывать или в случае ошибки тупо запускать конвертацию вручную ибо искать что и где смысла имхо нет а ошибка частая ))